# Alineado Titulos

Tags: html, css

En mi codigo:

```css
#lista1{
 border:8px solid #EAF2F8;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right:18px;
 border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: double;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
}

 #lista2{
 border:8px solid #EAF2F8;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right:18px;
 border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: double;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px; 
    text-align: center;
 }

.botonera1{
 float:left;
 margin-right:30px;
 position: relative;
    top: 85px; 
    text-align: center;
}

#second{
color: black;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
padding-left: 33px;
}

#one{
color: black;
position: relative;
top: 45px; 
padding-left: 33px;
}

fieldset { 

border:1px solid #CACFD2;

 }

body,td,th {
 color: #FDFEFE;
}

legend {
color: black;
text-align: center;
}

ul{
list-style:none;
counter-reset:li;
padding:10px;
left:-8px;
width:100px;
}

li{ /* Styles of each element */
width:100px;
position:relative;
left:0;
margin:0 0 1px 12px;
padding:4px 5px;
}

ul li:before{
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute; 
left: -30px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -13px;
background: #85C1E9; /* background color of the numbers */
height: 1.9em;
width: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
}

ul li:after{
position: absolute;
content: '';
left: -2px;
margin-top: -.7em; 
top: 50%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
border-left:10px solid #5DADE2; /* background color of the right arrow*/
}

ul li a{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;   
font-size:15px;
}

ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
*padding: .4em;
margin: .5em 0 .5em 0.4em;
background: #ddd;
transition: all .3s ease-out;
text-decoration:none;
transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

ul li:hover{
background: #EAF2F8; /* Background color on mouseover */
}   
ul li a:hover{
color:#444; /* Link color on mouseover */
margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo-frame">
   <h4 id="one">Tabla A</h4>
   <ul id="lista1">
   <li>Item1</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
   <li>Item3</li>
   <li>Item4</li>
   </ul>

   <div class="botonera1"> 
   <fieldset>
   <legend>Move rows</legend> 
   <input value=" « " onclick="moveRows(destTable,sourceTable)" type="button"></input>
   <input value=" » " onclick="moveRows(sourceTable,destTable)" type="button"></input>
   </fieldset>
   </div>
  <h4 id="second">Tabla B</h4>
   <ul id="lista2">
   <li>Item5</li>
   <li>Item6</li>
   <li>Item7</li>
    
   </ul>
```

Tan solo quiero centrar el titulo **Tabla B** en su tabla correspondiente, he usado el Padding-left y no me funciona, ¿alguien que me pueda ayudar?.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el centrado de títulos? ¿Ha revisado la documentación de MDN?

Answer (score 2):

El elemento ya está posicionado de manera relativa. Cambiá **padding-left** por **left**, y ya.

```css
#lista1{
 border:8px solid #EAF2F8;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right:18px;
 border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: double;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
}

 #lista2{
 border:8px solid #EAF2F8;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right:18px;
 border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: double;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px; 
    text-align: center;
 }

.botonera1{
 float:left;
 margin-right:30px;
 position: relative;
    top: 85px; 
    text-align: center;
}

#second{
color: black;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
left: 33px;
}

#one{
color: black;
position: relative;
top: 45px; 
padding-left: 33px;
}

fieldset { 

border:1px solid #CACFD2;

 }

body,td,th {
 color: #FDFEFE;
}

legend {
color: black;
text-align: center;
}

ul{
list-style:none;
counter-reset:li;
padding:10px;
left:-8px;
width:100px;
}

li{ /* Styles of each element */
width:100px;
position:relative;
left:0;
margin:0 0 1px 12px;
padding:4px 5px;
}

ul li:before{
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li;
position: absolute; 
left: -30px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -13px;
background: #85C1E9; /* background color of the numbers */
height: 1.9em;
width: 2em;
line-height: 2em;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
font-size: 14px;
}

ul li:after{
position: absolute;
content: '';
left: -2px;
margin-top: -.7em; 
top: 50%;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-top: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
border-left:10px solid #5DADE2; /* background color of the right arrow*/
}

ul li a{
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;   
font-size:15px;
}

ul li {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: .4em .4em .4em .8em;
*padding: .4em;
margin: .5em 0 .5em 0.4em;
background: #ddd;
transition: all .3s ease-out;
text-decoration:none;
transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

ul li:hover{
background: #EAF2F8; /* Background color on mouseover */
}   
ul li a:hover{
color:#444; /* Link color on mouseover */
margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo-frame">
   <h4 id="one">Tabla A</h4>
   <ul id="lista1">
   <li>Item1</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
   <li>Item3</li>
   <li>Item4</li>
   </ul>

   <div class="botonera1"> 
   <fieldset>
   <legend>Move rows</legend> 
   <input value=" « " onclick="moveRows(destTable,sourceTable)" type="button"></input>
   <input value=" » " onclick="moveRows(sourceTable,destTable)" type="button"></input>
   </fieldset>
   </div>
  <h4 id="second">Tabla B</h4>
   <ul id="lista2">
   <li>Item5</li>
   <li>Item6</li>
   <li>Item7</li>
    
   </ul>
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono, fijate que me agarraba por igual el padding-left, pero tenia que poner **320px**  y no es tan conveniente, existe una manera mas eficas de poner los tituos?

Comment: @ReinosRic tendrias que poner cada tabla dentro de un `section` y en los estilos por ejemplo: #second{width: 100%; text-alingn: center; }